# "bin" не является внутренней или внешней командой

Tags: php, консоль, phpstorm, symfony, path

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Не работают команды плагина maker в symfony 5. PATH для php прописан. Также, не работает команда  из директории "bin"

Comment: А слэш после bin  точно правильный стоит?

Comment: И тот, и тот пробовал. И без указания в директории, прямо из бин

Comment: А прямо из bin  что пишет?

Comment: Я не знаком с php, но сдается мне, тут проблема, все же, в shell. Поэтому попробовал у себя с первым попавшимся приложением. С правильным слэшем (\\) нормально запускается. С непрвильным (/) - "bin" не является внутренней или внешней командой

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов, тогда команда начинается с "console list make" - выдаст "console" не является внутренней или внешней командой

Comment: ("bin\console" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.) - выдал с другим слешем

Comment: Выдает именно "bin" не является внутренней или внешней командой          К сожалению, это была моя единственная мысль

Answer (score 0):

Поставь после `bin` **\** вместо **/**. Вот и все

Comment: Выдает "bin\console" Не является внутренней или внешней командой. Я уже гуглил этот вопрос, остальные его решали подключением в PATH php. Но у меня команды php работают, а команды плагина в фреймворке не работают. composer тоже работает

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
php bin/console ...
```